# RDF schemas, ontologies for software libraries?

Tags: rdf, ontology, semantic-web

Are there RDF schemas, ontologies for software libraries? Let's say I'm a Lisp programmer familiar with quicklisp. Or I'm a C programmer using numerical packages. Or a MS programmer using DLLs. Has any software libraries like these been "semantic webbed" with RDF triples? If not, where might I start? I'm guessing there exist XML or JSON data management for libraries, correct?

Comment: Please paste 3-4 example triples.

Comment: Is there a category, class for Software?

Comment: http://www.ontobee.org/ontology/SWO?iri=http://www.ebi.ac.uk/swo/SWO_0000001?